# Sending Items to specific partitions

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm looking for a way to send structures to pre-determined partitions so that they can be used by another RDD

Lets say I have two RDDs of key-value pairs

```
val a:RDD[(Int, Foo)]
val b:RDD[(Int, Foo)]

val aStructure = a.reduceByKey(//reduce into large data structure)
b.mapPartitions{
    iter =>
         val usefulItem = aStructure(samePartitionKey)
         iter.map(//process iterator) 
}
```

How could I go about setting up the Partition such that the specific data structure I need will be present for the mapPartition but I won't have the extra overhead of sending over all values (which would happen if I were to make a broadcast variable).

One thought I have been having is to store the objects in HDFS but I'm not sure if that would be a suboptimal solution.

Another thought I am currently exploring is whether there is some way I can create a custom Partition or Partitioner that could hold the data structure (Although that might get too complicated and become problematic)

thank you for your help!

edit:

Pangea makes a very good point that I should offer some more specifics. Essentially I'm given and RDD of SparseVectors and an RDD of inverted indexes. The inverted index objects are quite large.

My hope is to do a MapPartitions within the RDD of vectors where I can compare each vector to the inverted index. The issue is that I only NEED one inverted index object per partition and doing a join would cause me to have a lot of copies of that index.

```
val vectors:RDD[(Int, SparseVector)]

val invertedIndexes:RDD[(Int, InvIndex)] = a.reduceByKey(generateInvertedIndex)
vectors:RDD.mapPartitions{
    iter =>
         val invIndex = invertedIndexes(samePartitionKey)
         iter.map(invIndex.calculateSimilarity(_))
         ) 
}
```

Comment: give us a sample of how you are expecting the data in aStructure etc. examples get you more answers

Answer (score 0):

A `Partitioner` is a function that, given a generic element, will return in which partition it belongs. It also decides the number of partitions. 
There's a form of `reduceByKey` that takes a partitioner as an argument.
If I am understanding correctly your question, you want the data be partitioned while doing the reduce.
See the example:

```
// create example data
val a =sc.parallelize(List( (1,1),(1,2), (2,3),(2,4) ) )
// create simple sample partitioner - 2 partitions, one for odd
// one for even key.hashCode. You should put your partitioning logic here
val p = new Partitioner { def numPartitions: Int = 2; def getPartition(key:Any) = key.hashCode % 2 }
// your reduceByKey function. Sample: just add
val f = (a:Int,b:Int) => a + b
val rdd = a.reduceByKey(p, f)
// here your rdd will be partitioned the way you want with the number
// of partitions you want
rdd.partitions.size
res8: Int = 2

rdd.map() .. // go on with your processing
```

Comment: Hi @RobertoCongiu, So this is somewhat close to what I want. The issue is that once I have placed the reduced values into the correct partitions. I want to later be able to access those localized values while doing a mapPartitions on a different RDD. Do you have any thoughts on how I could do that?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do with the other RDD? If you need to join two `RDD`s, you don't need to do mapPartitions on that as `join` is smart enough to detect the RDDs have the same partitioner.

Comment: Essentially I'm given and RDD of sparsevectors and an RDD of inverted indexes. The inverted index objects are quite large. My hope is to do a MapPartitions within the RDD of vectors where I can compare each vector to the inverted index. The issue is that I only NEED one inverted index object per partition and doing a join would cause me to have a lot of copies of that index.

Comment: So you have one large inverted index per partition, and each one will need to be loaded by each executor. How big is the inverted index ?

Comment: It depends how large the user makes the bucket. The bucket is a predefined percentage of the total vector space (So if there are 1000 vectors and the user decides they want 10 buckets, each bucket will hold 100 values). Of course it will need to be storable in a single object, but can still be quite large.